Did Isaac Newton boil his watch?
Through Google Gemini I was referred to a weird anecdote about Isaac Newton. The story goes more or less like this: Newton was absent-minded, he wanted to boil an egg, and ended up boiling his watch.
Here are some examples of the use of the anecdote, it is quite popular:

From some blog
From one or more mediation books
Even a modern learning English textbook
Even this book with references fails to put a reference on that. The following quote cites Brewster's biography of Newton but it is not there

The oldest version I could find is from 1868 from an English composition text.
So the story is out there but is this based on any real source? I cannot find it.

Read the English composition text you linked at page 79: it is clear that the stories are fables invented by the author. On the other hand, it is the usual tale of the great scientist who is unable to deal with the mundane reality, cf. The Astrologer who Fell into a Well

On the other hand, Newton's distraction is well known, and there are first-hand sources that show it. These include some letters from his assistant during the composition of the Principia, Humphry Newton (not a relative), see here

For example "At some seldom Times when he design'd to dine in the Hall, would turn to the left hand, & go out into the street, where making a stop, when he found his Mistake, would hastily turn back, & then sometimes instead of going into the Hall, would return to his Chamber again."

Another source is the memoirs of William Stukeley, a personal friend of Newton's, see here

E.g. " e.g. "At Cambridg I often heard storys of his absence of mind, from common things of life. As when he has been in the hall at dinner, he has quite neglected to help himself; and the cloth has been taken away before he has eaten any thing. That sometime, when on surplice days; he would goe toward Saint Mary's church, insted of college chapel. or perhaps has gone in his surplice to dinner, in the hall  that when he had friends to entertain at his chamber, if he stept in to his study for a bottle of wine, & a thought came into his head, he would sit down to paper, & forget his friends."
